# El Proyecto rust-lang.org donde se guarda en Windows 10, cual es su Path?

Tags: rust

Estoy usando rust-lang.org e instale con cargo un generador de archivos llamado Crowbook estoy buscando su directorio raíz para modificar un archivo .tex pero no lo encuentro ni a rust ni a crowbook, uso Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

La ruta de este proyecto es la siguiente :

`C:\Users\user\.cargo\bin`

Se ve en el inicio cuando instalas Rust dentro de la consola.